# Min swaps to sort unordered consecutive integers

Tags: python, sorting

You are given an unordered array consisting of consecutive integers `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]` without any duplicates. You are allowed to swap any two elements. You need to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order. The code what i have got ,timed out for a few test cases. Is there any way that we can optimise the code?

My code is as follows:

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    lst=[ele+1 for ele in range(len(arr))]
    cnt=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if(lst[i]!=arr[i]):
            k=arr.index(lst[i])
            arr[i],arr[k]=arr[k],arr[i]
            cnt=cnt+1
    return cnt
```

Comment: To do it in no swaps with `O(n)` efficiency on the list `[1..n]`, you would optimally use [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), or the subtype [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) which is optimized for exactly this type of problem.

Comment: In general otherwise, [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) have better efficiency (`n log(n)`) (including number of swaps), and I think both of these can be run in-place.

Comment: Are consecutive integers not already in ascending order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to generate a reference list `lst` because you should know that `n` in `arr` should be in the index `n-1` to be ascending. Also, doing `k=arr.index(lst[i])` requires `O(n)` time to search, and which is complete unnecessary. Here's my solution:

```py
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    total_swaps = 0
    start = 0
    while start < len(arr):
        if arr[start] == start + 1:
            start += 1
            continue
        arr[arr[start] - 1], arr[start] = arr[start], arr[arr[start] - 1]
        total_swaps += 1
    return total_swaps
```

If I guess it right, it's a question on Hackerrank, and this was my solution by the time passed the tests. :P

This algorithm starts at position one and swaps the items under the cursor directly into their correct positions.  When the correct item is swapped into this position it increments the cursor to the next item and repeats the process.

This is more efficient than stepping through the array sequentially, swapping the correct item into each position, because you don't have to work out exactly where the correct item is located within the tail of the list.

Comment: Would you please tell me what's the name of the algorithm or if it has no name, the idea is similar to which sorting algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

I used the logic given in link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Def9kMtZCNA

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
# element usually at element value-1 index value
# eg, 1 at index 0, 2 at index 1.....  
counter=0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] != i+1:
        while arr[i] != i+1:
            temp=arr[arr[i]-1]
            arr[arr[i]-1]=arr[i]
            arr[i]=temp
            counter+=1
            
    else:
        continue
        
return counter
```